# How many times can we call back() method in one script in Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

When i am trying to call back() method more than once in my code.the script is not running as expected.Here is my script
@Test

```
public void testfun() throws Exception{
        WebDriver d= new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html");
        assertEquals("Overview",d.getTitle());
        d.switchTo().frame(d.findElement(By.name("packageListFrame")));
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='com/thoughtworks/selenium/package-frame.html']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        d.navigate().back();
        d.switchTo().parentFrame();
        d.switchTo().frame(d.findElement(By.name("packageFrame")));
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='AddApplicationCache']"));
        d.navigate().back();
        d.switchTo().parentFrame();
        d.switchTo().frame(d.findElement(By.name("classFrame"))).click();
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='org/openqa/selenium/firefox/package-summary.html']")).click();

    }
```

Any one with answers?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'not as expected'? do you get any errors, what is happenning? can you explain

Comment: d.navigate().back(); after d.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='AddApplicationCache']"));; is not working.i want to move to the home page after opening AddApplicationCache page.B'coz of this the following lines of code are not getting executed

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: arran work with ur brain